# WebAPI 2.0 Post Not Deserializing List<T> Property

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, xml-deserialization

I have reviewed every similar article I can find here and tried anything that looked like it might work with no success (obv since I am now asking the question).

I have a webAPI 2.0 controller with a POST action that takes in an object of type `Reservation`.  This object contains, among other things, a property called `Items` which is of type `EquipmentItems`. As you can imagine, this is a List property.  I send the reservation object over (using `PostAsJsonAsync("api/Reservation", reservation).Result` if it matters to anyone).

When I land in the API controller, the `Reservation` object is completely populated with everything except what is in the `EquipmentItems`property.

In the spirit of full disclosure, the `Items` property within the `Reservation` class, is actually defined as a List where T is `IItemData` interface.  `EquimpentItem` inherits from `IItemData` tho, so not sure if that complicates matters.

Can the native controller deserializer not handle List where T is interface?

What I know does work is defining the List as a regular array.  That works very well, but I have other requirements that have navigated me towards using List.

Any suggestions on how to get that List property deserialized correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. If you are trying to deserialize into a `List<ISomething>`, then it will not work. The reason is the deserialization operation does not know which ISomething you wish to actually create (you cannot init an ISomething, because its not a concrete class). You will need to change the service interface to expose a concrete class for the list. (ie. `List<Something>`).