# WebAPI 2 not deserializing List<string> property of FromBody object in POST request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, json-deserialization, asp.net-apicontroller

In one of my WebAPI 2 applications, I'm having trouble deserializing a `List<string>` property of a `FromBody` object. (The list stays empty, while the other properties are deserialized correctly.)

Whatever I do, the property only seems to deserialize correctly if I change the property to a `string[]`. Unfortunately for me, the property needs to be of type `List<string>`.

According to [another question I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008864/webapi-2-0-post-not-deserializing-listt-property), I should be able to deserialize to a `List<T>`, as long as `T` is not an `Interface`.

Is there anyone who has an idea what I could be doing wrong?

**Controller:**

```
public class ProjectsController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]Project project)
    {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

**Project object class:**

```
public class Project
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }

    private List<string> _comments;
    public List<string> Comments 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _comments ?? new List<string>();
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _comments)
                _comments = value;
        } 
    }

    public Project () { }

    // Other methods
}
```

**Request JSON:**

```
{
    "Title": "Test",
    "Details": "Test",
    "Comments":
    [
        "Comment1",
        "Comment2"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to recreate the list instance? `Comments` should probably simply be `public List<string> Comments { get; set; }`

Comment: @vc74 The problem does indeed have something to do with creating a new instance. The reason for that piece of code is that I don't want to be able to get a `null` version of `Comments`.

Comment: then you can: `List<string> Comments { get; set; } = new List<string>()`

Comment: `Comments` will still return `null` if it is set to `null` later in the code.

Comment: if it is really a requirement, add code to your setter to prevent setting a null value

Comment: When you expose any sort of collection through a public property, please never, ever allow it to 1) be `null` 2) be set to `null` from the outside. Make the setter private and you'll never have to worry about the collection being null. Null collections are evil and should be killed with fire. Initialize them in the constructor, or right where you declare them.

Comment: Additionally, hell will freeze over before a few collections that get initialized and not used will cause a performance problem.

Comment: @s.m. "Make the setter private" and you'll prevent the JSON serializer to work properly

Comment: @vc74 are we talking about JSON.NET? Because in that case there are multiple ways to make it work even with private setters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to @vc74 and @s.m. , I managed to update my project object class to look like the following to make it work the way I want it to:

```
public class Project
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }

    private List<string> _comments = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Comments 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _comments;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _comments)
            {
                if (value == null)
                    _comments = new List<string>();
                else
                    _comments = value;
            }
        } 
    }

    public Project () { }

    // Other methods
}
```

**Instead of** trying to **prevent getting** a `null` value from `Comments`, I had to **prevent setting** the value to `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
public class Project
{
    public List<string> Comments {get; set;}
    public Project () 
    { 
        Comments = new List<string>();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not creating a new `List<string>` when `Comments` is `null` indeed solves the issue. The problem with this code is that, in this way, `Comments` can still return `null` if it has been reset, which I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: @DylanVB when you expose any sort of collection through a public property, please never allow it to 1) be `null` 2) be set to `null` from the outside. Make the setter private and you'll never have to worry about the collection being null. Null collections are evil, please kill them any time you can. Initialize them in the constructor, or right where you declare them.