# Web API Controller model returns null

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, model, controller

When I use Web API controller with FROMBody, the model always returns `null`.

The model for Product object as below with `ProductID` and List of Order object:

```
public class ProductModel
{
    [Required]
    public string productID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public List<Order> order { get; set; }

}
public class Order
{
    public string orderId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public IHttpActionResult PostProduct([FromBody]ProductModel model)
{
    var jsonContent = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(model);
}
```

The JSON sample used in POSTMAN below. Noted that When passed in the Product with 1 Order, I don't have the enclose the Order object with a square bracket `[]` this is due to the end system consume the Controller always pass in without the `[]` for single product.

When debug it, the Order is always null. It works fine as long as I enclosed the Order object with `[]`.

```
{
    "productID":"1",
    "order":{
        "orderId":"1-88",
        "name":"Shoe"
        }
}
```

Is it possible to set up the model to handle both scenarios, single product and multiple product with the above JSON.

Am I trying something that impossible?

Answer (score 0):

For the problem where the list of orders are always null without the brackets, 
can you make the setter private for the collection and return a new initialized list if its empty? Or you can code a default constructor that initializes your list of Orders.

See: [WebAPI 2 not deserializing List<string> property of FromBody object in POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027613/webapi-2-not-deserializing-liststring-property-of-frombody-object-in-post-requ)

You can also try removing FromBody to bind to a complex type. For a custom handling of one or many product models try creating a custom model binder.